# Was the event natural or man-made in The Final Countdown (1980)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-final-countdown

[The Final Countdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Final_Countdown_(film)) is a 1980 American science fiction war film about a modern nuclear-powered aircraft carrier that travels through time to the day before the December 7, 1941, attack on Pearl Harbor.

The aircraft carrier goes through an event, a flashy hole created by some storm and the carrier is deported to 1941.

Now there is a similar mini-series named [The Triangle (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Triangle_(miniseries)) with similar event. Event here was created by some secret experiment conducted by government.

Coming to my question, it's nowhere hinted or depicted in The Final Countdown that the event was a result of a secret experiment by a private or government organization. But something was fishy about the way character "Warren Lasky" who is a civilian and sent on the ship by company of Richard Tideman, who we later find out is actually Commander Dick Owens who is left behind in 1941.

So my question is, was the event natural or created by Tideman?

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence or hint that the event was created by Tideman/Owens.

If you follow time travel "logic" Owens HAD to send Lasky because because Owens knew he would be there.

It's a circular paradox or as its commonly referred to as "timey-wimey".